# How to dockerize my flutter mobile app while using windows 10 system and make it possible to run the app on a mobile physical device?

Tags: flutter, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a mobile app developed in flutter , spring boot as backend and mysql as database.
I already dockerized spring boot and mysql. This is my first time trying to dockerize a flutter app.
Is there an example of dockerfile and docker-compose files that allows me to dockerize the app and become able to run it on a mobile device ? I have a windows system I'm working with right now.

Comment: what do you mean with "dockerize the flutter app"? I mean, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to build a docker image of my flutter app then run that image as a docker container to be able to use it on a mobile physical device

Comment: Why don't you create an APK to install the Flutter app on your physical device?

Comment: this is an assignment, I have already done that, now I need to do this by docker, do you have a link to a tutorial or anything that can help me do it ?

Comment: this blog [post](https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-dockerize-flutter-apps/) might be helpful